# java usage of parallelStream resulting into map

Tags: java, java-stream, fork-join

I have a single threaded code as follows :

```
private Map<Employee, EmployeeDeptMap> empToEmpDept(List<Employee> empList) {
    Map<Employee, EmployeeDeptMap> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Employee emp : empList) {
        map.put(emp, empDepartmentResolver.resolve(emp));
    }
    return map;
}
```

Here the code is sequentially traversing over the employee list and mapping department for each employee on basis of some rules which are abstract defined.

The requirement here is I want to run it in parallel so that multiple department resolution can happen in parallel and save time.

The list is quite big in size.

I tried with following piece of code but got stuck in applying the parallelism there

```
empList.parallelStream()
       .map(emp-> empDepartmentResolver.resolve(emp))
       .collect(Collectors.toMap())
```

Any suggestions what will be best way here to resolve them in parallel.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no `toMap` method in class `Collectors` that has no parameters. Perhaps you are looking for this [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) method? `Collectors.toMap(emp -> emp, emp -> empDepartmentResolver.resolve(emp))`

Comment: What do you mean, "got stuck in applying the parallelism"?  That looks like it should do it as well as anything can, assuming you resolve @Abra's comment.

Comment: Takeaway for the future: the [`map` method of the `Stream` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) has nothing to do with the [`Map` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 2):

As @Abra mentioned, you need to pass parameters to define how the Map should be created. You could try this code below:

```
Map<Employee, EmployeeDeptMap> map = empList
        .parallelStream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), empDepartmentResolver::resolve));
```

Comment: in this code Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), empDepartmentResolver::resolve)  is not specifying that the key of hashMap will be Employee ?  i need to return map of <Employee, EmployeeDeptMap>

Comment: `Function.identity()` works same as `e -> e`, so the key of the map we created would be the "T" of `Stream<T>` where T = Employee